# Unity C# problem with camera, camera goes white

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I made a script for my camera for following the player.When I play the game, game view goes white, even if on scene view all is fine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 playerpos;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        playerpos.x = player.position.x;

        transform.position = playerpos;
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the script, have you tried to disable it and enter play mode?

Comment: yes, I tried it and all goes fine.It renders anything, I tried to attach the camera as a child to the player, it s working fine, but i only want to follow the x axes

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the player is blocking the camera (because the camera is inside the player). Try adding some offset by adding a Vector3 as a variable and adding it on to the transform.position.

The offset could be used so that the camera is in front of the player, or in a third person angle.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 playerpos;
    public Vector3 offset;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        playerpos.x = player.position.x;
        transform.position = playerpos + offset;
        
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you guys! Solved it! This site is awesome